# Executar .java que importa outra classe no terminal

Tags: java, ubuntu, terminal

Estou tentando executar o meu programa no terminal, como ele importa uma outra classe estou usando o comando:

```
javac -cp ./IO.jar MeuPrograma.java
```

O programa compila é gerado o .class. Porem ao executar com:

```
java -cp ./IO.jar MeuPrograma
```

me é retornado no terminal o seguinte erro:

> Erro: Não foi possível localizar nem carregar a classe principal MeuPrograma Causada por: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MeuPrograma

Como eu consigo executar o meu programa no terminal usando essa outra classe?

OBS: a classe q eu uso no programa esta no mesmo diretório que o .java e o .class

[image: Imagem do erro no terminal]

Comment: Qual é o nome completo da classe `MeuPrograma`?

Comment: Guia_02 quando eu compilo/executo eu uso o nome da classe que no programa esta: public class Guia_02{}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O diretório em que se encontra o `.class` também deve ser informado no parâmetro `cp`.

O nome completo da classe deve ser especificado, algo como `snickers.guia.MeuPrograma`.

No seu caso, o suficiente deve ser:

```
java -cp ./:./IO.jar MeuPrograma
```

Se isso não funcionar, o problema que costuma ocorrer, é definir uma `package`, e colocar ela como caminho do `classpath`:

```
package snickers;
class Guia_02 {
}
```

Chamando `java -cp ./:./IO.jar snickers.MeuPrograma` não funcionará.
O Java espera que a classe esteja dentro do diretório `snickers`. Mesmo mudando para caminhos absolutos `java -cp "/home/bluorchid/Área de Trabalho/snickers/:/home/bluorchid/IO.jar" snickers.MeuPrograma` não funcionará.

O certo é algo como  `java -cp "/home/bluorchid/Área de Trabalho/:/home/bluorchid/IO.jar snickers.MeuPrograma"`.

Comment: Vc poderia, por favor, editar com o exemplo do comando como eu fiz na pergunta ?

Comment: Seu exemplo não ficou muito claro para mim. Ainda não consegui usar o comando.:/

Answer (score 2):

Você tem que instanciar a classe dentro da classe que está sendo executada.

OutraClasse outra = new OutraClasse();

outra.metodo();